# I need Excel to close when I close a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

Been looking for answers all over and none of them work. I need Excel to completely quit when someone tries to close the UserForm.

Currently I have this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this code?  Is this code firing when the form is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `UserForm_QueryClose` event. You can determine what code raised this event by checking the value of the `CloseMode` parameter in this event and then close Excel from there.

See below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    'for reference; you don't need this in your case, but it is useful
    'If ((CloseMode And VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormCode) = VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormCode) _               'user clicked button that calls 'Unload Me'
    'Or ((CloseMode And VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu) = VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu) _     'user clicked default Red "X" button 
    'Then   
        'do some stuff 

    'End If

    ExitApp

End Sub

Private Sub ExitApp()

    If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
        Application.Quit

    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

    Unload Me   'this would raise the QueryClose event

End Sub
```

Comment: @RobB It will work for windows or Mac. Even In Excel 2016 for mac (where microsoft discontinued support for userforms), you can import a `UserForm` into the VBE, run it like normal. You just won't have designer support.

Answer (score 0):

### Better Safe Than Sorry

If you're really sure there is only one workbook open then you can use this:

```
Sub AppQuit()
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

But if not, you better try this for one or multiple open workbooks (recommended):

```
Sub AppQuitAll()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        wb.Saved = True
    Next
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```